# How to package dependency JARs as part of project JAR using maven

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have 2 maven projects

1) My Utils Project - imports datecalc-common as a dependency, contains my custom utility classes. Note that it doesn't have a main class.

2) My Main Project - imports 'My Utils Project' as a dependency.

[image]
'My Main Project' shows the error 'Cannot find class HolidayCalculator'.

My Utils Project-pom.xml is given below.

***How do I modify it so that the dependency jars are included as part of 'My Utils Project'.jar ?***

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>      
    </properties>   
    <groupId>com.mycompany.mycommoncode</groupId>
    <artifactId>myutilsjar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.12-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myutilsjar</name>
    <description>Common Date Utils used by my classes</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.objectlab.kit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datecalc-common</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.objectlab.kit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datecalc-jdk8</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
         </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>my maven url</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>       
</project>
```

**NOTE: I DO NOT want to use 'shade' plugin. Is there any other way of doing this?**

Comment: Why don't you like to use maven-shade-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve that same issue some months ago. I wrote a small library that was to be shared between many projects and I wanted to add it to maven.
This is what I did.

### For your "Utils project"

Compile it using maven-assembly-plugin:

Add this to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Build the library with it's dependencies using the following command:

> mvn clean compile assembly:attached

### For your main project

Add this plugin to your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-external</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/sso-client-1.0.jar</file>
                        <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                        <groupId>SSOClient</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sso-client</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

As you can see, I wrote a custom SSO Client.

This will read the jar you compiled in the previous step, and make it available as a dependency. I decided to place it in the resources folder of the main project. The version has to match the one in your "utils project".

Also add the dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>SSOClient</groupId>
        <artifactId>sso-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

That's it! You can now reference the classes of the package in your main project.

Let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Maven **Shade Plugin** provides the capability to package your artifact in a "uber-jar", that is to say a jar including all dependencies required to run the project. If needed this plugin also supports packages shading (renaming) for some of the dependencies.
More info at:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html#

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I do not want to use a shade plugin, is there any other way of doing this?